# How change cave position of this line renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, draw, renderer

I am using the following code to draw a curved dotted line using a line renderer(Copied from the net). It's working but the curve is forming downward like a boat. I want to draw the curve in the opposite direction. I tried adjusting the values but no luck. can anyone can please say how to do this with this code? or can suggest me  new set of code

NB- I only have very basic knowledge in programming.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Point1;
    public Transform Point2;
    public Transform Point3;
    public LineRenderer linerenderer;
    public float vertexCount = 12;
    public float Point2Ypositio = 2;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        linerenderer.SetWidth(10, 10);
    }

   
    public void buttonPress()
    {
         Point2.transform.position = new Vector3((Point1.transform.position.x + Point3.transform.position.x)/2, Point2Ypositio, (Point1.transform.position.z + Point3.transform.position.z) *2);
        var pointList = new List<Vector3>();

        for(float ratio = 0;ratio<=1;ratio+= 1/vertexCount)
        {
            var tangent1 = Vector3.Lerp(Point1.position, Point2.position, ratio);
            var tangent2 = Vector3.Lerp(Point2.position, Point3.position, ratio);
            var curve = Vector3.Lerp(tangent1, tangent2, ratio);

            pointList.Add(curve);
        }

        linerenderer.positionCount = pointList.Count;
        linerenderer.SetPositions(pointList.ToArray());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Modify the positions of your control points in the scene (Point1, Point2, Point3). Likely just Point2 needs to move down if i understand the issue correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Point2Ypositio =600

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Point1;
    public Transform Point2;
    public Transform Point3;
    public LineRenderer linerenderer;
    public float vertexCount = 12;
    public float Point2Ypositio = 600;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        linerenderer.SetWidth(10, 10);
    }

   
    public void buttonPress()
    {
         Point2.transform.position = new Vector3((Point1.transform.position.x + Point3.transform.position.x)/2, Point2Ypositio, (Point1.transform.position.z + Point3.transform.position.z) *2);
        var pointList = new List<Vector3>();

        for(float ratio = 0;ratio<=1;ratio+= 1/vertexCount)
        {
            var tangent1 = Vector3.Lerp(Point1.position, Point2.position, ratio);
            var tangent2 = Vector3.Lerp(Point2.position, Point3.position, ratio);
            var curve = Vector3.Lerp(tangent1, tangent2, ratio);

            pointList.Add(curve);
        }

        linerenderer.positionCount = pointList.Count;
        linerenderer.SetPositions(pointList.ToArray());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).